# Web service and AdomdDataReader

Tags: web-services

I created Web service with this Web Method:

```
 public void Add( string kurs11,   string aktivnost11,  string godina11, string mesec11,   string dan11,  string sat11,   string brst11)
 {

 AdomdConnection cn = new AdomdConnection("location=localhost;Initial Catalog=MZ");
 AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand();
 cmd.Connection = cn;
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  t.*,Predict ([Modul]) as [Modul]  From   [Ph D] NATURAL PREDICTION JOIN (SELECT @kurs as [Id Kursa], @aktivnost as [Aktivnost], @godina as [Godina], @mesec as [Mesec],@dan as [Dan ime],@sat as [Sat],@brst as [Broj Studenata]) AS t  ";

 AdomdParameter kurs1;
 kurs1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
 kurs1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 kurs1.ParameterName = "kurs";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(kurs1);
 cmd.Parameters["kurs"].Value = kurs11;

 AdomdParameter aktivnost1;
 aktivnost1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
 aktivnost1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 aktivnost1.ParameterName = "aktivnost";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(aktivnost1);
 cmd.Parameters["aktivnost"].Value = aktivnost11;

 AdomdParameter godina1;
 godina1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
 godina1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 godina1.ParameterName = "godina";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(godina1);
 cmd.Parameters["godina"].Value = godina11;


 AdomdParameter mesec1;
 mesec1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
 mesec1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 mesec1.ParameterName = "mesec";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(mesec1);
 cmd.Parameters["mesec"].Value = mesec11;

 AdomdParameter dan1;
 dan1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
 dan1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 dan1.ParameterName = "dan";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(dan1);
 cmd.Parameters["dan"].Value = dan11;

 AdomdParameter sat1;
 sat1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
 sat1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 sat1.ParameterName = "sat";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(sat1);
 cmd.Parameters["sat"].Value = sat11;

 AdomdParameter brst1;
 brst1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
 brst1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 brst1.ParameterName = "brst";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(brst1);
 cmd.Parameters["brst"].Value = brst11;

 cn.Open();
 AdomdDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


}
```

But, when I invoke this method I get empty page. How can I see the results?
This query returns results in table, for example like this

kurs    aktivost       godina   mesec   dan         sat      brst    modul

1         edit           2013      2       Friday     12       75       forum

Comment: What "results" are you looking for? Even if this was a normal method, unrelated to web services, the method returns `void`.

Comment: Also, are you using ASMX web services? ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I expected results as I gave example. I see just blank page. What should I do?

Comment: I think you don't understand web services. There is no reason for you to get anything _other_ than a blank page. Your method doesn't return anything.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Probably don't :) Now I should consume this service with php, but from Moodle LMS. I am trying to create plugin and call this service with multiple parameters. Thank you

Comment: Start simpler. Create a service that accepts two integers and returns the sum. Hint: the method signature would be `int Method(int a, int b)`

Comment: Maybe see http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you. I tried this, it's working. But, in my example, i need to consume web service from php.

Comment: Great. I suggested it because it might help you create a web service which can be consumed from .NET. It should then be possible to consume the same web service from PHP. Unfortunately, I don't know how to consume a web service from PHP, but I'm sure there are many questions about that already on [so].